# how to call php function in js with parameters

Tags: javascript, php, function

i need to call php function in js with pass parameter(js variable) to function :
there is any way to use php in js?
this worked:
 `let fulld = "<?= gregorian_to_jalali('2023', '10', '2', '/'); ?>";`

but for this i got syntax error:  syntax error, unexpected token ";"
`let year = '2023';`
`let fulld = "<?= gregorian_to_jalali(?>"+year+"<?, '10', '2', '/');?>";`

is this possible?

Comment: You'd have to call your PHP with AJAX; PHP runs on the server, while JS is on the client. By the time the JS runs, the PHP doesn't exist anymore.